# How to get the textfield value in blur: function() for validation - extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

hi I am a fresher in extjs technology.. please help me in understanding the concept.

I have added a text field. I need to validate the value when the tab is out of focus

```
blur: function () {
 if (_____> 7000) {
  Ext.Msg.alert('Alert', 'Sorry, You Exceeded the Limit');
 }
},
```

I don't know how to get the value from textfield. I tried something but it doesn't work.

Comment: which version you are using

Comment: Field validation on blur is done [out of the box](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-validateOnBlur). Why code it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

blur event will get two input paramter. in that first paramter is the field that you want.

[blur ref](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-event-blur)

```
blur: function (field) {
 if (field.getValue() > 7000) {
  Ext.Msg.alert('Alert', 'Sorry, You Exceeded the Limit');
 }
},
```

and i suggest to use numberfield for numbers.